# Why does AutoMapper throw exceptions when implemented according to documentation?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, automapper

I've tried to use AutoMapper in an ASP.NET MVC application, but can't get this AutoMapper to stop hitting me with AutoMapperConfigurationExceptions, when I view the details AutoMapper basically tells me that it can't map any property, ie. profile not found?!?

I've done everything according to the documentation on the AutoMapper website.

**Global.asax:**

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    // neither of those two ways works
    Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.AddProfiles(typeof(ImageEntity2GalleryModelMapping)));
    Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.AddProfiles(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()));
}
```

**Mapping profile:**

```
public class ImageEntity2GalleryModelMapping : Profile
{
    // take note that this used to be an override of Configure() but the
    // AutoMapper API has changed recently to favor Ctor now
    public ImageEntity2GalleryModelMapping()
    {
        CreateMap<Image, GalleryModel>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.ImageId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ImageId))
            // and so on
            ;
    }
}
```

**Inside the Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(Mapper.Map<GalleryModel>(_dbContext.Images.ToList()));
}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: according to the documentation all simple collectiontypes should work out of the box with no further implementation effort, meaning that if I have a mapping <X, Y>, then <IEnumerable<X>, IEnumerable<Y>> should also work

Comment: Please edit your question and post the full stacktrace of the exception.

Comment: Map a list to a list: `View(Mapper.Map<IList<GalleryModel>>(`

Answer (score 0):

OK, just found out, that I do need to map to a collection class (I was under the impression that AutoMapper implicitly takes care of this).

Just changes from this

```
return View(Mapper.Map<GalleryModel>(_dbContext.Images));
```

to this

```
return View(Mapper.Map<IList<GalleryModel>>(_dbContext.Images));
```

and now it works ;)

Comment: If you tell AutoMapper how to map an `Image` to a `GalleryModel`, then it automatically knows how to map a collection of `Image` to a collection of `GalleryModel`. But the line of code you have in your controller in your original post is asking AM to map a collection of `Image` to a single `GalleryModel`, which it doesn't know how to do.